# POWERSHELL: making a literal string out of a expanded string

Tags: variables, powershell-3.0, string-literals

I have a string that I build from a couple sources to do matching with later, the short of my code so far is:

```
$temp = "some\good"
if("some text" -match $temp)
```

My representation of $temp is simple but actually it is built, this is an example of how it can get built, so no, in this case changing " for ' to pass a literal to $temp won't work. If I hard code the if to use a literal string version of $temp, it works so its a matter of converting the value in $temp to a literal string.

I get the following error when I run my code:
parsing "some\good" - Unrecognized escape sequence \g.
At [not important]
+             if($temp2 -match $temp)
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Converting to literal string" won't help you here. String is a string, it only matters how it's being used, i.e. if the content is being interpreted in some way.

`-match` operates on regex, and that's it, you can't change that, you'd have to escape every all characters that have a meaning in regex.
But you can use `select-string` instead, which has a switch for simple matching:

```
$text = "some text"
$patt = "some\good"
if (($text | Select-String -SimpleMatch -Pattern $patt | Measure-Object).count -gt 0) {
    Write-Host "match"
} else {
    Write-Host "nomatch"
}
```

Comment: i had to check to make the variable i piped in wasn't a $null or empty, otherwise that hit the spot right on, thanks.